# undefined local variable or method `user' - How to get name to appear instead of number.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a table which list a set amount of managers. In the Manager User Id column I am trying to get the name to appear instead of the integer. I have the following relationships

**User model**

```
has_many :roles, :through => :roles_users
  has_many :projects, :foreign_key => "manager_user_id"
```

**Projects**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => "manager_user_id"
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
    <tr>


  <td><%= project.project_number %></td>
  <td><%= project.project_name %></td>
  **<td><%= user.project.manager_user_id%></td>**
  <td><center><%= link_to image_tag("icons/user.png"), project %></center></td>
  <td><center><%= link_to image_tag("icons/user_edit.png"), edit_project_path(project) %></center></td>
  <td><center><%= link_to image_tag("icons/user_delete.png"), project, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></center></td>

    </tr>
```

I have tried the following:

- project.user.manager_user_id
- user.project.manager_user_id

Neither of these work and I get this error: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<#:0xb14cf5c>

What is it that I am doing wrong. I used the above similar method for another table and this worked fine.

Comment: show you controller code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks from your view that you have `project` defined in the view, but not `user`. That being so, you definitely want the `project.user` form. That also makes sense in that a Project only has one associated User, whereas a User has multiple Projects, so `user.project` is an array.

Secondly, remember that `manager_user_id` is a member of `Project`, not of `User`, so `project.user.manager_user_id` won't work.

I suspect you want something like `project.user.name`.

Answer (score 1):

Like it's says, it's undefined.

`<%= project.user.name %>` should work if you've coded AR associations properly and if you have `project` variable available. You can also define `to_s` method in you User model, so when you do `<%= user %>` in a view, user name is displayed, instead of a "number". Again, as long as you've prepared `user` first.

example:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def to_s
     name
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that in `project.user.manager_user_id` you are accesing a field that is not in the users table, it is in the projects table, so with `project.user.name` you should be able to retrieve the user name.

When you make `project.user` Rails instantiates the user associated to that project so you have access to every method and field in the User model.

I'm assuming that you have loaded your project in your controller, but not the user, hence the error `undefined local variable or method 'user' for #<#:0xb14cf5c>` when you try to execute `user.project.manager_user_id`.